# Magento 2 : Disallow Specific Phone Number

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation, input

We would like to disallow some specific phone numbers, especially in the checkout.
For example the phone number: 0000000000 or 1111111111.

How can we disallow these phone numbers?

Comment: Try to extend phone number input validation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/validations/custom-validation.html, there you can create some rules (or regex) for phone numbers you are not allow

Comment: you can do this by validate-digits-range set it upper than this no. or create your own custom validation class that shoot an error if the same number is in array